# Client certificate in Rust using Hyper

Tags: rust, hyper

I have been writing a client in Rust which makes a request to a server with a client certificate (Pkcs12). Although this has been answered [How to make a request with client certificate in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059266/how-to-make-a-request-with-client-certificate-in-rust), the code doesn't compile as it is. If I make some modifications like replacing '?' by call to unwrap() function,

Code:

```
let tls_conn = TlsConnector::builder().unwrap()
        .identity(cert).unwrap()
        .build().unwrap();
```

Error:

```
let tls_conn = TlsConnector::builder().unwrap()
   |  ____________________^
18 | |         .identity(cert).unwrap()
   | |________________________________^ cannot move out of borrowed content.
```

I rewrote the above line of code and broke it down into multiple lines for debugging:

```
let ref mut init_tls_conn_builder = TlsConnector::builder().unwrap();
let ref mut tls_conn_builder = init_tls_conn_builder.identity(cert).unwrap();
let tls_conn = tls_conn_builder.build().unwrap();
```

I get the error as follows:

```
let tls_conn = tls_conn_builder.build().unwrap();
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content.
```

I am new to Rust and seeking help on this, can anyone please share an example code which compiles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot move out of borrowed content when unwrapping a box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338659/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-when-unwrapping-a-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any `mut` references here. The builder pattern is create smth mutable (`TlsConnector::builder().unwrap()`), mutate it (`tls_conn_builder.identity(cert)`) and then get the result (`build`). Try this code

```
let mut tls_conn_builder = TlsConnector::builder().unwrap();
tls_conn_builder.identity(cert);
let tls_conn = tls_conn_builder.build().unwrap();
```